# Visual Studio 2019: Xamarin Automatic provisioning Team Authentication error

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm getting error while trying to authenticate the team in Visual Studio Preview 2019.
In Xamarin iOS project properties -> iOS Bundle Signing -> Automatic Provisioning.

Although the XCode 11 on MacOS Catalina I'm getting this error complaining about a low version of XCode.
Is there any Visual Studio setting I'm missing or what do I need to setup?

[image]

Comment: Hi , from screenshot can't know where other problems is . I think first you need to update the version of Xcode to check whether work.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT It seems so, but on the connected Mac I run the latest XCode 11 so this error must be related to sth. else.

Comment: OK, in Visual Studio , click tools -> options.. -> Xamarin -> Apple Accounts , check whether exist Apple Account . If no , you need to add one manually .

Comment: The account does exist. I use it on the Mac XCode project.

Comment: OK , I found that you are using Preview version of visual studio . Then first you can have a try with stable version to check that .Second , automatic provisioning is not compatible with free provisioning. In order to use automatic provisioning, you must have a paid Apple Developer Program account.

Comment: The problem is the stable version has bug which prevents from loading the data to the Team dropdown.
I will check the license, which I should have. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If solved ,remember to share the news here .

Comment: Will do. There are just some troubles with the renewal of my subscription. As soon as I confirm it was caused by the subscription, I'll update it.

Comment: OK , look forward to good news .